# Table inside form andular validation

Tags: html, angularjs, dom

I have a quite ugly form, that looks like this:

```
form#cookingForm.table-responsive(role='form' ng-submit='cook()')
    table.table.table-hover(style='text-align: center')
        thead
            tr
                td.col-md-4.thead-sold {{'ORIGINAL_RECIPE' | translate}}
                td.col-md-4.thead-sold {{'YOUR_COOKING' | translate}}
        tbody(style='vertical-align: middle' ng-repeat='ingredient in selectedRecipe.ingredients')
            tr
                td {{ingredient.name}}: {{ingredient.weight}}
                td
                    table(style='width:100%')
                        tr
                            td
                                input(type='number' ng-model='batch.weight' required)
                            td {{'GRAMM' | translate}}
            tr
                td {{'EXP' | translate}}
                td
                    date-picker
            tr
                td {{'COLOR' | translate}}
                td(ng-style='{background: selectedRecipe.color}')

            p {{!!cookingForm.$invalid}}
 div.col-md-12
        button.btn.btn-default.pull-right(type='submit' ng-disabled='cookingFrom.$invalid') {{'COOK' | translate}}
```

The `cookingFrom.$invalid` always returns false, even if I add letters to the number input field (tied to the `batch.weight`), even though the outline of the field gets red.

Comment: Isn't the form only added to the `$scope` is it has a `name` attribute?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Add it as an answer. I did not add the name attribute, I only added it as `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form will only become part of the `$scope` is you use the `name` attribute:

```
form(name='myForm')
```

Now you can use `myForm.$invalid`